# How to generate the string with variable in symfony

Tags: php, javascript, symfony

I want to use the code:

```
document.getElementById("btn").setAttribute("href", "{{ path('deletecontact', { 'id': "idx" }) }}");
```

to add attribute to the button to delete the chosed contact.

The idx is the parameter of javascript function. Now the id is always the string "idx", but if I remove the "" to idx, there will be error of symfony.

I have tried to use "+" to linked the string like:

```
"{{ path('deletecontact', { 'id': "+idx+" }) }}"
```

But the result is that it will put the string "+idx+" as id.

I have also tried this:

```
var str1 = "{{ path('deletecontact', { 'id': ";
var str2 = str1 + idx;
var str3 = str2 +" }) }}";
```

However, there will also error in symfony.

So how can I just put the variable in to the string? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: You have a parsing issue in the value of your 'href' attribute. Look at the ' and " you have.. they don't work.

Comment: I think you are mixing up things. Your `{{ path }}` is evaluated by php (via twig) whereas `idx` is a javascript-variable. This means the value for `idx` is only available at runtime (client side) and `path` is rendered prior to that (on the server). You have to specify the url path as a string to javascript, e.g. `href: "/path/matching/your/route/" + idx`. Alternatively there is a bundle which makes Symfony-routing accessible to javascript: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

Comment: Another workaround would be to create the btn like this: `<button id="btn" href="{{ path(..., { 'id': 0 }) }}">...</button>`, i.e. just create the button with a valid path. You can then access the url in your javascript and use it as a kind of template-url replacing the id as needed, e.g. via regexp.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved the problem by the second methods. That's useful. Thx. @mahok